# Find Max tabindex Within Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabindex

Using jQuery/Javascript, how do I find the maximum `tabindex` value that exists on a given form `#formID`?

And before you ask (because I know people will) I haven't tried anything because I really have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Then you should start [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: @Teemu sorry, I know how to use selectors and everything in jQuery, but I don't know how to use all of that to start solving my problem.

Comment: Use the Attribute Selector ["tabindex"] to get all childelements of this form. Then simple save the values of this attribute in an array, sort it, last element = highest tabIndex

Answer (score 11):

This is one way:

```
var max = -1;
$('#formID [tabindex]').attr('tabindex', function (a, b) {
    max = Math.max(max, +b);
});
```

`max = -1` indicates, that there's no tabindexes in the form, or elements are excluded from tabbing order.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaorL6sm/1/).

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript:

```
var maxTabIndex = -1;

document.getElementById("formID").querySelectorAll("input").forEach((e) => {
    if (!isNaN(e.tabIndex)) {
        if (e.tabIndex > maxTabIndex) {
            maxTabIndex = e.tabIndex;
        }
    }
});
```